# Dynamically loading options of a select control on expand event using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, select, expand

I am wondering if there is an easy way of doing the following:

When a user clicks on my dropdown list's expand arrow, I need to make a call to an outside service and fetch 5 records and populate the options of the select and display them dynamically. I understand that I need to bind a model to the select and angular will take care of it automatically but I am having problems understanding how to capture the expand event of the select. I tried using ng-click directive but I had no luck.

Comment: I think onFocus is the only event that occurs when you click on the "dropdown list's expand arrow"

Comment: @john Thank you, I was trying to avoid using html event attributes, but I guess it's the only way to go in this scenario. Is there any disadvantages of mixing angular directives and event attributes?

Comment: I am not aware of any disadvantages. I know that we do it here all of the time. You know tight timelines and all.

Comment: Have you looked at using [ui-select2](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2)?

Comment: I am trying to avoid adding new javascript library to the project since I have to convince the project team(angularjs purists), but sure I will have a look.

Answer (score 0):

after struggling with it for an hour, I made it work using ng-click directive. Only problem I have is since I catch ng-click and fetch the data, it doesn't expand the select, I need to click on the dropdown second time to open the select.